# Radio button in WPF Application selected but not visible

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, radio-button

I have a radio button in a WPF Application which works normally in  Windows 7.

However in some XP machines, the radio button selection is not visible but the clicked event is fired.

Why does this happen? Is this a repaint issue or a computer settings issue?

**UPDATE**
This problem comes only in the computer which uses Windows Classic Theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add a label inside the radiobutton as below:

```
<RadioButton
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                              GroupName="InstallType"
                              Margin="2,3.5"
                              Foreground="Black"                
                              >
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
                        </RadioButton>
```

I saw the solution here:
http://www.carlos-roque.com/2011/07/25/making-wpf-checkbox-and-radiobutton-display-correctly-in-windows-classic-theme/

Answer (score 1):

You can check with the template used by radio button. Make sure the brushes/colors used in windows 7 are available in XP.

These links should provide some more help

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751600.aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709925.aspx

Check for the "Checked State"

Comment: This is the code for the radiobutton. There is no style or anything else specific defined:  '<RadioButton
              Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
              GroupName="BeanType"
              Margin="2,3.5"
              Foreground="White"   
              />'

Answer (score 0):

You should check the version of the .NET framework. on these XP machines

Comment: What effect does the .NET version have on radio button display?

Comment: I had the same problem with different basic controls that they would not be redndered correctly on different .Net version depending on which they are build, and on which they are executed.